# Addressing specific geojson features

Tags: leaflet

I've built a map and drew some nice geojson features (points) on it via L.circle()

```
function loadNodes(map, geojson) {
   return L.geoJson(feature, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
               return L.circle(latlng, 50, merge_options(cirkelOpties, {
                    fillColor: feature.properties.kleur,
                }));
            }
          }
        ).addTo(kaart);
}
```

In the geojson feature I have an unique id: `feature.properties.node_id` Which I want to use to target the specific circle from another (part of my) javascript.

What is the best way to find and reposition the drawn circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a reference of the circles in a variable scope outside of the `pointToLayer` callback:

```
var circles = {};

function loadNodes(map, geojson) {
    return L.geoJson(feature, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var circle = L.circle(latlng, 50, merge_options(cirkelOpties, {
                    fillColor: feature.properties.kleur,
                }));
            circles[feature.properties.node_id] = circle;
            }
        }
    ).addTo(kaart);
}

geojson.once('load', function(){
    // Do something with a specific circle, e.g.:

    circles[1234].remove();
});
```